# Remove elements of list not present in another list in python

Tags: python, file, text

Say that I have two lists:

```py
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list2 = ["a", "b"]
```

How can I find the elements of `list1` that are not present in `list2`?

Edit: edited to properly explain the issue I was having. Looking back on this, there are already better answers for this question that I did not properly search for at the time.

The solution I was looking for is something like the following:

```py
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list2 = ["a", "b"]

output = []

for i in list1:
    if i not in list2:
        output.append(i)

print(i)
```

Comment: So the result should be Cow? Also, have you tried implementing this yet? Can you show your code and indicate what difficulties you are having in your implementation?

Comment: Also do the positions of each word matter? Or is it just, if it sees one words is in both, it doesn't remove it?

Comment: Also is it a large file ? keep the duplicates or not ?

Comment: Yes, no I am asking which functions I should use, one second, let me upload it

Comment: Positions do not matter, just need to be exported as strings. It would not be large, possibly a few kb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read though the master file and put the lines into a set, then compare the lines in the second file to the words in the master set:

**Code:**

```
# read in the master file and put each line into a set
with open('master') as f:
    master = {w.strip() for w in f.readlines()}

# read through the second file and keep each line not in master
with open('file1') as f:
    allowed = [w.strip() for w in f.readlines() if w.strip() not in master]

# show the allowed lines
for w in allowed:
    print(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming both your lists are files):

```
master = open('master.txt', 'r').read()
f = open('file.txt', 'r').read()
f_arr = f.split('\n')
master_arr = master.split('\n')
fin_arr = []
for i in range(len(f_arr)):
    if not f_arr[i] in master_arr:
         fin_arr.append(f_arr[i])
final = '\n'.join(fin_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, this does not include the file reading/writing.

*The data:*

```
file = """
cow
duck
sheep
"""

master_record = """
duck
sheep
cat
dog
"""
```

Now for the one-liner list comprehension no one wants to look at:

```
print([i for i in [x for x in file.replace('\n', ' ').split(' ') if x in master_record.replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')] if i])
```

That will return a list of all the words in file that also appear in the master record.

Splitting it up:

```
found = []

# Loop through ever word in `file`, replacing newlines with spaces,
for word in file.replace('\n', ' ').split(' '):
    # Check if the word is in the master file,
    if word in master_record.replace('\n', ' ').split(' '):
        # Make sure the word contains something,
        if word:
            # Add this word to found,
            found += [word]

# Print what we found,
print(found)
```

Hope this helps!

-Coolq